# Why does iPhone Music app show me "Apple Music" logo instead of my iTunes songs?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I synced all of the music in my iTunes Library to my iPhone (like it was an iPod).

I've been listening to the music in my Jeep for weeks by plugging into the USB port and choosing songs and playlists from the in-car radio's touchscreen.  (So I know the music is on the iPhone.)

Today, I want to listen to my music with headphones.  Thought I'd try Siri ... I told Siri to "Play Accept Yourself by The Smiths", and sure enough she played it!  (I thought it was pretty cool that worked, actually.)

When the song ended, I thought I'd chose something manually.

On the iPhone I touched the "Music" app/button on the home screen, it took me to a photo of a girl wearing headphones and the "Apple Music" logo.

No lists of songs, no other options.

I went to the "Settings" app, and selected "Music" and I noticed that "Show Apple Music" was switched to ON.  So I turned it OFF.

Went back to the "Music" app, and there's still nothing but the photo of the girl and the "Apple Music" logo.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I see the songs that are my iPhone?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/238587/22003 what you name the "Apple Music" logo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned more ... I may have an answer to my question.

According to this [article here](http://www.mcelhearn.com/you-cant-turn-off-apple-music-on-ios) ... when I told Siri to "Play Accept Yourself by The Smiths", she may have played that from Apple Music, not from my own library.

That would explain why "Apple Music" got turned on.

But I don't know why this would happen because I did not renew my Apple Music subscription after the trial last summer.

After ensuring the "Show Apple Music" setting was OFF, I powered off my iPhone.  Restarted, and it looks like I'm back to "iPod" mode in Music.

Comment: my dad's iphone's music app froze on the apple music page, but i just tapped the home button twice, swiped up on the music app, reopened it, and then it was either no longer on the apple music page or it wasnt frozen any longer so i was able to navigate away from it. one of those two. (So its possible that you didnt have to restart it.)

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem also from time to time.

What solves it for me is to either wait until that screen with the person wearing headphones finishes loading (it will try to sell Apple Music to you) and dismiss it or just close the app and reopen it a bunch of times.

If neither of those works, try restarting your iPhone and trying them again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i found a work around in a simple way.

1. Close the music app and force close from the phone memory.
2. Put your phone in Airplane mode.
3. Open the music app.
4. When it opens, click on Songs with the cursor sign down
5. Choose last option, only downloaded music.
6. Close music app from home button.
7. Remove the airplane mode from the phone.
8. Reopen the music app, now it works fine, no more the Music Apple Logo.

This is how I made it work on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. There should be two buttons below the girl. One is to show Apple Music and one to go to your song library. Those two buttons disappeared in my case and somehow they appeared again.

You might need to do nothing other than wait it out.

Comment: I also had the buttons disappear. I don't know why the 'Music' sell screen was suddenly appearing, or how Music got turned on. Turning off Music and restarting the phone brought the buttons back for me, allowing me to navigate to my music.