# Music / iPhone: no access to library, just an image dead end: "girl with headphones"

Tags: iphone, music

I have an iPhone 6 running iOS 9.3.1.

I just made a synchronization with its host MacBook Pro with no problem
and which might not be related in any way to the problem I witness.

Upon opening Music on this iPhone, I just get this 
image:

[image: image on Music / iPhone picture]
, with apparently not any function visible on the screen
or hidden anywhere.

I tried to click within the usual corners
where hidden functions are placed but didn't get any reaction.

I can close the application, reopen it.

Same dead end.

My iPhone isn't connected to any network outside of my phone provider.
I don't have any Internet connection (on phone, on Bluetooth or on Wi-Fi).

I never used iCloud to stay on basic problems (there are already enough problems thus far).
Here are my `Settings > Music`:
[image: Settings > Music]

I did not try to shutdown the iPhone since I would like to understand
what is this problem and its origin before trying to fix or kill it.

---

Among the technical details:

- I am not using Apple Music (I don't even know how to).
- I am not using Siri.
- I am not using iCloud.

Any **very similar** question which involve any of these three functions might be a **false duplicate**.

Apple doesn't aknowledge if this is a bug but seems already aware that
there is a real problem with the `Music` software since the number of 
users reporting the exact same problem is regularly growing.
Their actual receipe is just "restart it" which I dont consider a
professionnal answer.

---

If you encountered the same problem, do you have any hint of which operation or configuration error might lead to it?

What may help to analyze this problem?

Comment: I don't use Apple Music and to be honnest I haven't yet looked at what this application or service might be. I'm simply not interested.•• return •• This similar question didn't bring me any clear explanation to the problem I want to understand and avoid definetly.

Comment: Try some of the others then - http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=girl+headphones

Comment: Thank you for your hint to search for relevant questions.•• return •• I am in the process of reviewing all of them in a search for a correct explanation and a way to avoid this silly **interface dead end**.

Comment: Didn't find any correct explanation or analysis :). The answers tagged as correct are of very low quality.

Comment: Adding a new question asking the same thing will not increase the quality of the answers, that's why it got closed as a duplicate. If you are looking for better answers, consider editing more details into the original question and/or set a bounty.

Comment: → patrix: I made purposefully a new question because none of the one I found was clearly presenting the problem and at least contained a screen capture of the dead end picture. Rather than to make a complete edit on top of low quality **discussions**, I made my own question which was much faster and cleaner (for me).•• return •• If this method seems you a failure on a way to get better quality answers, just delete my question. I won't invest time on a problem where all questions are of really low quality.